# On a polynomial with roots in $[1,3]$ that are also of the form $2+\csc\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> If the roots of the equation $x^2+bx+c=0$ are  $\alpha,\beta$ such that $1\leq \alpha,\beta\leq 3$ and also
>
> given that $(\csc  \theta+2)^2+b(\csc \theta+2)+c=0$ satisfy for two different values of $\csc \theta$
>
> Then value of $|b+c|$ and $\min (x^2+bx+c)$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write it as $x^2+bx+c = (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=x^2-(\alpha+\beta )x+\alpha\beta$

So $\alpha +\beta = -b$ and $\alpha \beta = c$

and $(\csc \theta+2)^2+b(\csc \theta +2)+c = (\csc \theta-\alpha')(\csc \theta-\beta')=\csc^2 \theta -(\alpha'+\beta' )\csc \theta+\alpha'\beta'$

So $$\csc^2 \theta+(4+b)\csc \theta+(4+2b+c) = \csc^2 \theta -(\alpha'+\beta' )\csc \theta+\alpha'\beta'$$

So $\alpha '+\beta'=-(4+b)$ and $\alpha'\beta'=(4+2b+c)$

Now how can i solve it after that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Clearly, $\csc\theta_1,\csc\theta_2$ are the two roots of $$x^2+bx+c=0$$ Now if $\theta$  is real, $$\csc\theta+2\ge3$$ or $$\csc\theta+2\le1$$ So, the equality will follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $|\csc\theta|\ge1$, and hence $2+\csc\theta$ must lie *outside* $(1,3)$. Yet two distinct $2+\csc\theta$ values are the roots of the given quadratic, which is given to have roots within $[1,3]$. Hence the roots *are* 1 and 3 and the quadratic is
$$(x-1)(x-3)=x^2-4x+3=(x-2)^2-1$$
Thus $|b+c|=|-4+3|=1$ and $\min(x^2+bx+c)=-1$.